# Attach a handler to the "event" of autocomplete select with jQuery

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I'm using [Views Autocomplete Filters](http://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) on an exposed node title field. I would like to attach a handler to the "event" when the user selects one element from the autocomplete list without applying [this patch](http://drupal.org/node/365241#comment-6314864) which would actually trigger a "real" event.

For the simplest example: if the user has selected one element from the autocomplete list, show an alert() message. (I wouldn't do that because it's ugly, but it's the easiest demonstration of the solution.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a Drupal autocomplete field I had created, where I wanted the form submitted when an item from the dropdown was selected.

This blog post addressed the issue for me:  http://othermachines.com/blog/smart-autocomplete-navigation-drupal-7

The relevant JQuery code you'll want to look at on that page is this:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.programmeSearch = {
    attach: function (context) {

      $('#edit-autocomplete-field').focus(
        function(){
          $(this).val('');
      });

      $("#edit-autocomplete-field", context).bind('autocompleteSelect', function(event, node) {

        var key = $(node).data('autocompleteValue');
        var label = $(node).text();

        // If matches found...
        if (key != '0') {

          // Set the value of this field.
          $(this).val(label);

          // Redirect user to entity path.
          window.location = Drupal.settings.basePath + key;
        }
        else {

          // If no matches, reset.
          $(this).val('');
          $(this).focus();
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

You probably won't need all of that code.  Whatever you want to happen on the select event, put in the condition beginning with

```
if (key != '0') {
```